# Trying to make .exe with pyinstaller, but pyinstaller can't find google-cloud-bigquery

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyinstaller

### I've solved this problem already.

It's because of virtualenv. You need to install pyinstaller in virtual environment you are using.

---

I've tried some solutions, but still can't solve this problem,

1. adding hook path to `hookspath=[]`:
   'C:\python\lib\site-packages_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks\hook-google.cloud.bigquery.py'
2. using `--collect-submodules google` or `--collect-submodules google.cloud`
3. adding hidden import to `hiddenimports=[]`

It could go wrong even in the most simple program with single line like `from google.cloud import bigquery` in test.py

Some error message are as below:

`pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'google-cloud-bigquery' distribution was not found and is required by the application`

or while running the main.exe the terminal says

```
File "journey_renew_upgrade\main.py", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'bigquery' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)
```

Also, I am wondering if it is possible to use -D flag to make a directory, and copy google.cloud.bigquery into this directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I've solved this problem already.

It's because of virtualenv. You need to install pyinstaller in virtual environment you are using.